# appengine illegal key.path.element.type: __BlobInfo__ trying to delete blobstore values

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm experiencing an error that doesn't happen when I test the application on my machine but only after deployment.

I have some pictures associated with a parent item in the datastore and I have set up a query that deletes both the parent item and related pictures: datastore and blobstore values

I have a base key that I use as ancestor for all my items:

```
def base_key(group = 'default'):
    return db.Key.from_path('my_items', group)
```

I get the parent item and his attachments

```
parent = Parent.by_keyname(s)
attachments = Attachment.by_parent_keyname(s)
```

here's the implementation of those queries:

```
@classmethod # in Parent class
    def by_keyname(cls, s):
        item_k = db.Key.from_path('Parent', s, parent=base_key())
        item= db.get(item_k)
        return item

@classmethod # in Attachment class
    def by_parent_keyname(cls, s):
        item_k= db.Key.from_path('Parent', s, parent=base_key())
        q = Attachment.all()
        q.ancestor(item_k)
        results = q.fetch(20)
        return results
```

after I got parent and attachments I instanciate a list with all the keys whose elements I have to remove from datastore and blobstore:

```
entities_to_delete = [parent.key()]
            for a in attachments:
                entities_to_delete.append(a.key())
                entities_to_delete.append(
                    db.Key.from_path('__BlobInfo__', str(a.blob.key())))

            db.delete(entities_to_delete)
```

and this works perfectly on my machine but after deployment, if I test this request handler I get a server error, here is the error I log:

[image: appengine log]

[full size image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnBPj.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the development server and the live server have different ideas about what it means to delete a BlobInfo entity.  The most direct fix is to call the Blobstore `delete()` method for the blob keys:

```
entities_to_delete = []
blobs_to_delete = []
for a in attachments:
    entities_to_delete.append(upload.key())
    blobs_to_delete.append(upload.blob.key())
db.delete(entities_to_delete)
blobstore.delete(blobs_to_delete)
```

There might still be a way to construct a BlobInfo key in a way that `db.delete()` will accept, but the code you borrowed from my code sample is indeed inaccurate.  My apologies for the inconvenience, and thanks for asking me about it!

Comment: I'm getting this error: BadArgumentError: Expected an instance or iterable of (<class 'google.appengine.ext.db.Model'>, <class 'google.appengine.api.datastore_types.Key'>, <type 'basestring'>); received M16BnVIhzRJjRStWzosTLg== (a BlobKey).

Comment: maybe I should fire two different queries? one for datastore items and the other one for blobstore items?

Comment: if I pass objects rather than keys to db.delete I get a similar error: Expected an instance or iterable of (<class 'google.appengine.ext.db.Model'>, <class 'google.appengine.api.datastore_types.Key'>, <type 'basestring'>); received <google.appengine.ext.blobstore.blobstore.BlobInfo object at 0x00000000049CC278> (a BlobInfo)

Comment: I confirm that performing two different queries works. It seems like db.delete doesn't take BlobInfo instances or keys so I fire one transaction where I delete db.Model instances and another one, by datastore.delete where I pass BlobInfo instances

Comment: I took that piece of coode (db.Key.from_path('__BlobInfo__', str(a.blob.key())) here http://ae-book.appspot.com/code maybe it is outdated, I'm just noticing that on the book the code suggested is different, same thing on app engine documentation.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize it was my code that was broken. :) I can confirm that the code sample is broken on the live server in the way that you describe, and my answer is insufficient.  I'll fix my answer above later today. Just wanted to confirm this so I'm not wasting your time.

Comment: I have replaced my answer with one that works.  The new answer suggests and you've already figured: use two RPC calls and let the Blobstore API handle the BlobInfo keys.  I'll get this fixed in the code sample.  Thanks for bringing it to my attention!